# How to parse name=value^^name=value^^name=value

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing

**My Question:** It's very specific. I'm trying to think of the easiest way to parse the following text:

```
^^domain=domain_value^^version=version_value^^account_type=account_type_value^^username=username_value^^password=password_value^^type=type_value^^location=location_value^^id=xxx^^cuid=cuid_value^^
```

It will appear exactly like that every time. A few requirements:

- Not all of those key-value pairs will appear every time.
- They may be in a different order

I'm looking for code something like this:

```
private String[] getKeyValueInfo(String allStuff) {
  String domain = someAwesomeMethod("domain", allStuff);
  String version = someAwesomeMethod("version", allStuff);
  String account_type = someAwesomeMethod("account_type", allStuff);
  String username = someAwesomeMethod("username", allStuff);
  String password = someAwesomeMethod("password", allStuff);
  String type = someAwesomeMethod("password", allStuff);
  String location = someAwesomeMethod("location", allStuff);
  String id = someAwesomeMethod("id", allStuff);
  String cuid  = someAwesomeMethod("cuid", allStuff);
  return new String[] {domain, version, account_type, username, password, type, location, id, cuid};
}
```

What I don't know is what `someAwesomeMethod(String key, String allStuff)` should contain.

**What I was thinking:** Something like this:

```
private String someAwesomeMethod(String key, String allStuff) {
  Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("(?i)^^" + key + "=(.*?)^^", Pattern.DOTALL);
  Matcher matcher = patt.matcher(allStuff);
  if (matcher.find()) {
    return matcher.group(1);
  }
  return null;
}
```

**What's wrong with that:**

I'm worried it'd be a little slow/cumbersome if I had to do this a lot. So I'm looking for any tips/suggestions.

Comment: I take it [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) doesn't float your boat?

Comment: @RobertHarvey `.split()` still uses regex and you'd still have to parse out the keys and parameters.

Comment: That's alright.  Just split each of the splits again over `"="`.

Comment: This sounds like a premature optimization. Profile the program before you make an optimization, as I highly doubt this would be a bottleneck even if you called it thousands of times.

Comment: @m.buettner This would be a problem if either a key or the value contained a caret, which I suspect is the reason the OP is using two carets to split things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have to do it a lot, i'd make a map, something along the lines of

```
Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (String s : stuff.split("\\^\\^"))  // caret needs escaping
{  
    String[] kv = s.split("=");
    m.put(kv[0]) = kv[1];
}
```

then to lookup a key you'd just do `m.get("key")`

Answer (score 0):

String.split() will work for that

```
strVar = /* Your big long string */
String[] vars = strVar.split("\\^\\^"); // needs escaping
```